# How to make computed column not nullable?

Tags: sql-server-2005, default-value, calculated-columns, non-nullable

So far I've been using `ISNULL(dbo.fn_GetPrice(ItemId), 0)` to make it not nullable (rather call it default-valued, but whatever).

Is this the right way?

Comment: Which SQL dialect are you using?

Comment: You should clarify language, SQL dialect, database version, etc.

Comment: I'd prefer the ANSI standard COALESCE function, but ISNULL is fine.

Comment: It's not a good habit to be calling functions in the SELECT clause - it's the equivalent to using `SELECT ...(SELECT ...) FROM TABLE...`

Comment: @Shannon Severance: Why wouldn't post your comment as answer.  
@OMG Ponies: I already said that I need it for a computed-column, which SELECT is irrelevant.

Comment: @Shimmy: Didn't seem to be worthy of an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is the right way to do it.  By using the `isnull` function you are creating an expression that must return a value, no matter what.  This is evaluated by SQL Server to be a computed column that is `not null`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer the ANSI standard COALESCE function, but ISNULL is fine. To use COALESCE, define your computed column as:

```
COALESCE(dbo.fn_GetPrice(ItemId), 0)
```

**EDIT** Learn something new everyday. I did the following:

```
create table t (c1 int null
    , c2 as isnull(c1, 1) 
    , c3 as isnull(c1, null)
    , c4 as coalesce(c1, 1)
    , c5 as coalesce(c1, null)
    )

exec sp_help t
```

And c2 is indeed not nullable according to sp_help, but c4 is reported as being nullable, even though there is no way that coalesce expression could result in a null value.

Also as of 2008, I don't know whether the option exists in 2005, one can persist a computed column and add a constraint:

```
create table t (c1 int null
    , c2 as isnull(c1, 1) persisted not null
    , c3 as isnull(c1, null) persisted not null
    , c4 as coalesce(c1, 1) persisted not null
    , c5 as coalesce(c1, null) persisted not null
    )
go
insert into t (c1) values (null)
```

results in a constraint violation.

Comment: Woops!
i just find out that it doesn't cause the computed column to be non-nullable, since COALESCE could also be COALESCE(NULL, NULL), i.e. no guarantee for non-null result, I guess ISNULL is the only option.
I am so sorry for bothering you, I just found it out, I've already changed few locations in the DB cuz of it...

Comment: This answer should be removed, it does not work for the stated purpose of the post.